# how to let django view bigint field as datetime?

Tags: django, datetime

when django encounter a datetime field, it will popup a time box and let user click to select time. But right now in my project my table has a bigint field store  the current time in milliseconds for convention (System.currentTimeMillis() in Java). How do I let django view this field as a datetime object and display the time box in web ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution (or workaround) can be to define your own form with DateTimeField and provide the conversion from int => datetime when you create the form, and back (in the POST function).